# How to mock request to IndexedDB in react testing library/jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that shows a spinner until data retrieval is completed. But I do not take the data from the server, but from indexedDB, using the Dexie library.
How I can mock such request.
My code:

**useEffect inside component**

```
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(setData())
    }, [])
   
    if(isDataLoadng) {
      return <Spinner/>
    }
    
    return Component
```

**Thunk action**

```
import db from '../../indexedDB/db'

    export const setData = createAsyncThunk(
      `setData`,
      async (_, { getState }) => {
          const data =await db.data.toArray()
          return {data}
      }
    )
```

**indexed db file**

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';


const db = new Dexie("dataDB");
db.version(1).stores({
  data: 'id, name,
});


export default db
```

**My reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  data: [],
  isDataLoading: true,
}

const crudSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dataReducer',
  initialState: initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [setData.pending]: (state) => {
      state.isDataLoading = true
    },
    [setData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.data = action.payload.data
      state.isDataLoading = false
    },
  
  },
})
```

**My attempt**

**Test.test.js**

```
  import "fake-indexeddb/auto";
  import Dexie from "dexie";
            
   describe('Data tests', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      //my code bellow doesnt mock request
       const db = new Dexie("dataDB");
       db.version(1).stores({ data: 'id,name'})
 
       const table1 = db.table("data");
       await table1.bulkGet([])
    
       //How mock getting data from db here instead of my attempt
     })
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm in a similar situation and am curious